# how to pass labels in forward_hook in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I want to pass features, obtained after a specific module/layer, corresponding to the label `1` to another model called `my_model`. I would like to have a hook that accepts, in addition, to `model, input, output`, a new variable called `labels`, which are the batch labels. However, the current implementation does not do that. Is there a way to achieve similar functionality?

```
    def apply_my_model(self):
        def hook(model, input, output, labels):
            output[labels == 1] = self.my_model(output[labels == 1])
            return output

        return hook
```